# var_dump of result gives null value. But deeper inspection returns a integer

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [New Mysqli Object is Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302335/new-mysqli-object-is-null)

I just started with building my database class for my MVC framework. While building this I am experimenting with simple queries and tables in order to make it work properly.

I was trying to query the following:

> SELECT * FROM mvc_test

This should return 3 rows:

> 1 | test
>
> 2 | test2
>
> 3 | test3

I use the following method to query:

```
<?php $this->result = $this->conn->query($this->q); ?>
```

Where $this->conn is:

```
<?php 
 $this->conn = new mysqli($this->reg->conf->database['host'],
 $this->reg->conf->database['user'],
 $this->reg->conf->database['password'],
 $this->reg->conf->database['database']);
?>
```

Where $this->reg->conf->database contains all the values for host, database etc. This works, I have a connection.

Now, when I var_dump the result like this:

```
<?php var_dump($this->result); ?>
```

I get this:

> object(mysqli_result)[9]
>
> public 'current_field' => null
>
> public 'field_count' => null
>
> public 'lengths' => null
>
> public 'num_rows' => null
>
> public 'type' => null

But, as said before it should contain at least 3 rows, so I would expect num_rows to be '3'.

Now, when I var_dump the num_rows of the result like this:

```
<?php var_dump($this->result->num_rows); ?>
```

I get a 'int 3' as response.

Conclusion: in the first var_dump it's null, but with a deeper inspection I get a 3. So it reads 3 rows. When I add another row (the 4th), it returns a 4 as expected.

My question is: why is the var_dump not working properly? Why Does it say null at first, but with a deeper inspection it does have a value.

Thanks in advance, I'm really struggling with this one since I don't get any errors as well.

Comment: You need to call `fetch_assoc` or similar in a loop for each row to get the results.

Comment: What do you get if you use print_r instead of var_dump - print_r($this->result)?

Comment: Probably you should use `mysqli_fetch_object($this->result);`

Comment: @AleksG, that's not the problem. I want the var_dump to work for debugging.

Comment: @Abhijit, that returns the correct values. I tried var_export but gave the same bug. print_r works. Awkward that var_dump bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object is implemented "lazily", i.e. it does not retrieve data from the server until it's actually required (i.e. you access something from the result object).

`var_dump` doesn't seem to trigger the property getters so they are shown as `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems pretty strange though, since it works on the computer of a friend of mine. He has his own framework as well and also uses mysqli, he gets proper values returned when using var_dump on the result. It's weird. But thanks for the answer.