# Can't write/read from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to make a 1 on 1 chat website by learning as I progress, but I've come to a hault.

I can't write to the database.

I have four php files linked below.

- [Index](http://hastebin.com/garajabuya.xml)
- **Init:**

  ```
  session_start();

  define('LOGGED_IN', true);

  require 'classes/Core.php';
  require 'classes/Chat.php';

  ?>
  ```
- [Chat](http://hastebin.com/bofajerugo.coffee)
- **Core:**

  ```
  class Core {
  protected $db, $result;
  private $rows;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","root","");
  }

  public function query($sql) {
      $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
  }

  public function rows() {
      for($x = 1; $x <= $this->db->affected_rows; $x++) {
          $this->rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
      }
      return $this->rows;
  }
   }

  ?>
  ```

I have a MySql database set with WAMP.

P.S. Yes, I have opened the "< ? php" 
but it doesn't get displayed here.

Comment: Is the connection to DB successful? Plz, concentrate upon the erroneous code and don't put unrelated session stuff here.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the DB. And I don't know which code is erroneous, I wouldn't have posted it all.

Comment: What is the timestamp data type in your table?

Comment: what do you mean by *can't write to the database*? What happens, what errors are you receiving, what have you tried etc etc etc...

Comment: @Vishnu, It's a UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @lynks  On the index file, if you run it, there should be an Array fetched and printed. But I get nothing, not even an error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen you do not select a default database. You must either give a default database in

```
$this->db = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "mydatabase");
```

or select one later with

```
$this->db->select_db("mydatabase");
```

You also don't check the return values of the mysql calls. For example, add

```
public function query($sql) {
    $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($this->result === false) {
        echo $this->db->error;
    }
}
```

after your mysql statements, in order to see whether the statements succeed or fail.

For debugging purposes you can display the sql and corresponding result

```
public function query($sql) {
    var_dump($sql);
    $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    var_dump($this->result);
    echo $this->db->error;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, setting it as "mysql", but still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1877016 You must give the name of your database. What's the name, when you connect with phpmyadmin or mysql?

Comment: That's the name, it's "mysql".

Comment: @user1877016 `mysql` is the name of the system database. You should setup a database for your application only. Anyway, look at the updated answer for more.

Comment: @user1877016 Still nothing what? If you have an error, the error should be displayed. If you have no error, everything should be fine. You can try debugging your query with `var_dump`. See updated answer.

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Chat::query() in C:\wamp\www\core\classes\Chat.php on line 27` And the line 27 is the beginning of your code.

Comment: comment out your old Chat::query definition and try again

Comment: @user1877016 Insert the `var_dump` statements in your `Core::query` method.

Comment: Anyway, I have to sleep now. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @user1877016 This looks fine so far. Now you do the same for `rows()`, insert `var_dump($this->rows);` after fetching all rows.

Comment: @OlafDietsche don't rush with checking query results, cause user1877016 didn't prove, that he really connects to the database.

Comment: @user4035 If he didn't connect, the return value would have been `false` and there should have been shown an error "no database selected".

Comment: @OlafDietsche true. He gets nulls for every field of the response. It would be interesting to see the same query results from phpMyAdmin direct connection to the database.

Comment: @user4035 According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11285967/1741542 this behaviour is correct.