# Dynamically generated MySQLI prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a prepared statement to write an article to a database. There are some optional fields, which should not be written to the DB if left empty. That's why I want to use dynamically prepared statements. I've already found some answers here on SO, and generally speaking the solution is using `call_user_func_array()`. But this somehow does not seem to be working.

Code:

```
//generating query
$art_str = 'INSERT INTO table SET ';
$art_str.= 'col1=?';
$art_str.= ', col2=?';
$art_str.= ', col3=?';

$art_stmt_params = array(); //array with parameters for binding
$art_stmt_params[] = 'sss'; //$types

//obligated parameters (already been checked)
$art_stmt_params[] = $_POST['par1'];
$art_stmt_params[] = $_POST['par2'];
$art_stmt_params[] = $_POST['par3'];

//$articleParagraphs is an Array. Correctly generated and checked
if(isset($articleParagraphs)){
    $art_str.= ', col4=?'; //expanding query
    $art_stmt_params[0].= 's'; //adding type
    $art_stmt_params[] = json_encode($articleParagraphs); //adding parameter to array
}

if(!empty($_POST['par5'])){
    $art_str.= ', col5=?';
    $art_stmt_params[0].= 's';
    $art_stmt_params[] = $_POST['par5'];
}

if(!empty($_POST['par6'])){
    $art_str.= ', col6=?';
    $art_stmt_params[0].= 's';
    $art_stmt_params[] = $_POST['par6'];
}

$art_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($art_str); //$mysqli is correct
call_user_func_array(array($art_stmt, 'bind_param'), $art_stmt_params);

$art_stmt->execute();
$art_stmt->close();
```

The code above does not generate any errors. And code following the code above is also executed correctly. But nothing is written into the DB. Everything is correct: column names, table name, database connection, parameters which were posted. When I do a `var_dump()` on the `call_user_func_array()` however, it prints `NULL`. Also I'm using the prepared statements earlier on the same page, to write some meta data to the database. Since the paramaters here are always the same ones I haven't used dynamic prepared statements here, but `$stmt->bind_param(...)`. I hope you'll be able to help me with this issue. Thanks!

ps. This is my first time using prepared statements (it's been a while since I've been sql'ing)

Comment: What kind of answer you expect?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Either if there's something wrong in my code or why nothing is written to the database.

Comment: So, you want someone to read your code and execute it mentally, inside their head, taking notice of all execution errors - right?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'd call that a bit extreme, since I've stated other prepared statements are executed correctly in the same page and no errors are produced. I'd like to now for instance how a `var_dump()` on `call_user_func_array()` could return `NULL` or if I've made a (visible) mistake in my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict

Comment: @YourCommonSense I had already tried that, and as stated: no errors

Comment: Well, if no errors - then everything works well.

Comment: if that were the case, I'd probably not post a question here...

Comment: Is Autocommit turned on?  Is `table` really your table name? It happens to be a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: @OllieJones `table` is just a placeholder I put in the code here, in the actual application it's called differently and the name is certainly not on the reserved words list ;). I haven't touched Autocommit, nor do I know what it is. I'm going to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the cumulative value of $art_str.

Comment: `var_dump($art_str)` returns `string(51) "INSERT INTO articles SET col1=?, col2=?, col2=?"` This is when no optional parameters are given. Nothing is being written to the DB though...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posted on behalf of the OP:

I've managed to fix it, by creating `if(){}elseif(){}elseif` for each possible combinations of optional parameters and `$art_stmt->bind_param(...)`. Now it works. I still don't know why `call_user_func_array()` didn't work though.

Comment: Thanks for adding it as an answer. although it isn't really an answer but a quirky work-around.

Comment: That's okay - just bear in mind that since we have a data API here, and flags to specify that a question is answered, it's best for answers to be stored as answers. Though, as far as I know, there is no `is_quirky` boolean field `:-p`.