# Can't Insert into mySQLi DB using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

i revamped my mysqli db to insert values from my form into the db using prepared statements. **Thanks stackoverflow - i learned this is the way to go by reading up on this site.**

Changed my statements to look like below, but for some reason they aren't inserting into the db. What could I be doing wrong? I added '' around my strings but that did not work... not sure what I could be missing. I started from a tutorial and worked my way around to this set of code.

Any help getting my insert to work would be appreciated, I am new to mysqli prepared statements. Here is my code:

```
  <?php
  $con= new mysqli("localhost","admin1","default","sourcesDB");
  // Check connection

  if (mysqli_connect_erno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
  }

  $biotext = $_POST[$bio];

        $keywords= json_encode($_POST['Keyword_ID']);
        $assocs= json_encode($_POST['Associations']);
        $fname = $_Post['FName'];
        $mname = $_POST['MName'];
        $lname = $_POST['LName'];
        $suffix = $_POST['Suffix'];
        $dept = $_POST['Dept'];
        $title = $_POST['Title'];
        $title2 = $_POST['Title2'];
        $title3 = $_POST['Title3'];
        $edu = $_POST['Education'];
        $edu2 = $_POST['Education2'];
        $edu3 = $_POST['Education3'];
        $ph1 = $_POST['PH1'];
        $ph2 = $_POST['PH2'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $pic = $_POST['Pic'];
        $linkname = $_POST['LinkName'];
        $website = $_POST['Website'];
        $tags = $_POST['Tags'];
        $bio = $_POST['bioLinks'];


  $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO profileTable
   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ');

  $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssss', $fname, $mname, $lname, $suffix, $dept,
  $title, $title2, $titl3, $edu, $edu2, $edu3, $ph1, $ph2, $email,  $pic, $linkname,
  $bio, $website, $keywords, $tags, $assocs);

  if($stmt->execute()) {
echo '<div style="color: green;">Profile Added!</div>';
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='4; URL=addProfile.php'>";
  }
  else {
echo "Failed to insert";
  }

  $stmt->close();
```

Comment: `$title3` and `$titl3` no match. If/when one fails, then they all go down.

Comment: good catch @Fred-ii- i did change this but still no insert. I had one question... what if the first column in my db is "id" would this set the order of the insert off?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18457821/285587

Comment: Couldn't say for certain. Too many possible reasons at play. @MizAkita

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense is this mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); inserted before the $stmt->close(); function? if so, its not showing anything for me...

Comment: what's the point in turning error reporting AFTER all the possible errors?

Comment: @YourCommonSense you sent me the link...so i was assuming you were asking me to try it.???

Comment: Your `$fname` variable wont work as `$_Post` is not the same as `$_POST` php should be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer this question on my own... i added the names of the columns to insert into and then bound my params to my value. In the end, this is what ended up working flawlessly...

```
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO profileTable (FirName, MName, LaName,
         Suffix, Dept, Title, Title2, Title3, Education, Education2, Education3,
         PH1, PH2, Email, Photo, BioLK, Website, Keyword_ID, Tags, Associations) 
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"));

         {
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssssssss", $fname, $mname, $lname, $suffix, 
         $dept, $title, $title2, $title3, $edu, $edu2, $edu3, $ph1, $ph2, $email,
         $linkname, $bio, $website, $keywords, $tags, $assocs);

      $stmt->execute();
         echo '<div style="color: green;">Profile $fname $lname Added!</div>';
         echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='4; URL=addProfile.php'>";

       $stmt->close();

       mysqli_close($con);
        }
```