# stmt->execute() returning false?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

For some reason i am stuck on something that has been simple for me for the past year. Inserting data into databases. Today, i have been trying to fix what is wrong with this and i can not seem to understand why `stmt->execute()` is returning false?! I get no errors, even when i turn on PHP, and MySQLI errors. Here is my code :

```
else
{
    // We are all good, lets enter this person into our DB
    $CheckUser->close();
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, country, region, city, address, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
       $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $name, $email, $geoplugin->countryName, $geoplugin->regoin, $geoplugin->city, $address, $password, $random_salt); 
       if($insert_stmt->execute())
       {
            // Success, redirect the user to his page (Remember to login the user)
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
       }
       else
       {
            // Something happened
            echo "Something Happened";
       }
    }
}
```

On my page, `Something Happened" is being echoed. However, if i turn on MYSQLI Errors, then i just get a blank page after i submit. What am i doing wrong???

Comment: Use the error handling functions to display an error message instead of displaying the much less informative "*Something Happened*" message. And "*if i turn on MYSQLI Errors*" -- How do you enable them?

Comment: elaborate on "i turn on MYSQLI Errors" please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict

Comment: please wrap the PDO functions in a try...catch:

Comment: @YourCommonSense `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);`

Comment: @Adam You do realize this is not PDO. This is MySQLi

Comment: Maybe you made a typo in `$geoplugin->regoin` and meant to use `$geoplugin->region`? @EliteGamer

Comment: where do you call this command? before execute or after?

Comment: @Adam please DON'T wrap PDO functions in a try...catch: it doesn't make any sense, wrong and insecure

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was it. I can't believe that i did not catch that or that PHP did not throw an error. Thanks, post your answer and ill accept it.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was resolved. I posted my answer below, cheers. @EliteGamer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request to give an answer from my comment.

You might have made a typo in `$geoplugin->regoin` and meant to use `$geoplugin->region`?

Comment: Thanks again. It helps to have a fresh pair of eyes look over my code LOL.

Comment: Yes it does and you're quite welcome, was glad to help. @EliteGamer Cheers