# What does if($con->connect_errno) mean?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning php and i have a file that connects to a mysql database, i'd like to know what is the condition inside the brackets of the following "if structure" in the file, $con is an instance of the class mysqli:

```
if ($con->connect_errno)
{
echo "fail to connect to mysql";
}
```

I know that $con is invoking to connect_errno but what is conditioning if(what?){...}?

Comment: check this manual for better help:-http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

Answer (score 1):

That's a status flag for mysqli handles.
See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

It's not a function, but a property (or a "variable" if you will). It's `0` when the connection was correctly established. It contains other values (e.g. `1043`) for connection problems (such as wrong password, inavailable database server).

So the `if ($con->connect_errno)` check asserts that your `$con` instance is usable.

- When `->connect_errno == 0` then the [`if`](http://php.net/if) block will be skipped.
- If `->connect_errno > 0` (any other value) the error message will be printed out. (You'd more commonly see [`die()`](http://php.net/die), [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/trigger_error) or [`new Exception()`](http://php.net/newException()) than just an [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) there.)

Alternatively mysqli can be configured to [throw an error/exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict) by itself. Which would make this whole condition/block redundant.

Comment: (Btw, most people use [`PDO` rather than `mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) nowadays. Because that makes it much easier to handle parameter binding.)

Comment: ok then it would work with if ($con->connect_errno !=0) {echo "error";} but i keep without understanding what is conditioning in if(0){echo "error";} that is the same to if ($con->connect_errno){echo "error";}

Comment: Yes, that's the same. `if ($errno != 0) trigger_error();`

Comment: but i keep without understanding what is conditioning in if(0){echo "error";} = if ($con->connect_errno){echo "error";}  what is the condition?

Comment: "When ->connect_errno == 0 then the if block will be skipped."

Comment: yes i understand that but in line if ($con->connect_errno){echo "error"} i don't see any operator of comparison

Comment: That's an implicit boolean comparison. `if ($var)` is identical to `if ($var != 0)`.