# PHP cannot catch Error from within included file

Tags: php, mysqli, try-catch

i try to implement a fallback solution for when my database is not available. Somhow i do not manage to catch the error.

Call to create connection:

```
if(!$this->connection = mysqli_connect(
        $this->host,
        $this->name,
        $this->pass,
        $this->db
    )) { throw new Exception('Unable to connect to Database'); }
```

init.php to include dbClass

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../classes/Database.php';
$db = new Database();
$connection = $db->getConnection();
```

actual usage with try catch wrap

```
try {
        include __DIR__ . '/../out/script/content/config/init_direct.php';
        ... do stuff regulary
}catch (Exception $e) {
        ... do fallback stuff
}
```

i do not get into the catch block. for test purpose i just set the database offline.

Comment: Dont throw Exception, it 'll block you script and prevent your alternate solution to work.

Comment: now receive the error in my log - still not able to catch it ... [15-Oct-2015 16:26:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

 in C:\xampp\htdocs\finevisuals\out\script\content\classes\Database.php on line 29

[15-Oct-2015 16:26:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function set_charset() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\finevisuals\out\script\content\classes\Database.php on line 31

Comment: those aren't execeptions. they're warnings/errors. unless your `Database` class actually throws an exception, there'll be nothing to catch.

Comment: Well this seems to be true for the first one - however, the second is a Fatal error - shouldn't this get caught?

Comment: fatal errors cannot be caught. that's why they're fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several problems with your approach

- First, your problem is insufficient debugging. You just *assume* that exception has been thrown, but in reality it weren't.
- Second, this happened because mysqli_connect returns an object, not boolean you expect.
- Third, as you've been told in the comments, errors aren't exceptions and you cannot catch them.

Anyway, with mysqli you don't need to throw exceptions manually - this extension can throw them by itself, so, all you need is to [set the proper mode up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict) - an exception will be thrown which will be caught all right.