# Inserting data in database through modal and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert data from modal after user clicks submit button. But it is not working, I have 2 files index to display modal and PHP file to run connect MySQL and insert data into it. I don't think it recognizes submit action. I also have question how do I insert primary key id into database or does it adds automatically.

HTML submit code:

```
<button type="submit" action="add.php"class="btn">Finish!</button>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$cName = $_POST['form-name'];
$ser = $_POST['form-s-name'];
$link = $_POST['form-t'];
$info = $_POST['form-des'];


  $sql = "INSERT INTO crewlist(id, name,sname,linkname,description)
VALUES ('','".$cName."','".$ser."','".$link."','".$info."')";


mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    echo "<p>Added</p>";
```

Comment: Check column and values count ?? both are not same!1

Comment: If `id` is auto-generated, which it probably is, you don't need to `INSERT` that. An `AUTO_INCREMENT` column does this for you.

Comment: "do i insert primary key id into database or does it adds automatically" automatically if field is auto increment

Comment: please enable errors.so you can see the errors

Comment: don't know whether action attribute is supported by button or not :(

Comment: i added safe loop if mysql base connect is ok->print successful and if error print error. But nothing. Looks like submit buttom is not working, as i thought at first.-.

Answer (score 3):

The textbook way to do this is to use prepared statements:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,
  "INSERT INTO crewlist(name,sname,linkname,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss',
  $_POST['form-name'],
  $_POST['form-s-name'],
  $_POST['form-t'],
  $_POST['form-des']
);

$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

If you use prepared statements correctly you're guaranteed that your values are inserted with the proper escaping. Here I've used `s` for string, but there are other types listed in the documentation.

You'll want to enable [exceptions for errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict) in case you make a mistake.

If you're doing a lot of database work I'd strongly encourage you to use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) as they make interfacing with your records a lot more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using variables in sql query you should use it like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO crewlist(id, name,sname,linkname,description)
        VALUES ('','{$cName}','{$ser}','{$link}','{$info}')";
```

Comment: Sorry, this is [dangerously bad](http://bobby-tables.com/). The safe way to do this is to use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @tadman i know i am just suggesting the right way to use of sql query

Comment: thanks but when i click finish it still doesn't do anything

Comment: I'm sorry to be so difficult here but this is not the right way. Not only does this not escape data properly and will error out if any of those values contains `'`, but this is how you get your server hacked wide open. Using `bind_param` is not hard, and it's the absolute baseline.

Comment: echo the sql query and try to find the error by running it in phpmyadmin and try to use bind_param as @tadman also suggest's it will be more secure

Comment: i will, i just want to do it simple for first time, to see everything is working.

Comment: @swipeales A prepared statement is the simplest, most reliable way to get data in there. It will properly encode all your values.

Comment: hook me up with example link, do you think there is error in html submit code?

Comment: @swipeales is there any error which running the query to phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Vicky nothing happens it just closes modal when i click finish

Comment: @Vicky i am sorry dont know :)

Answer (score -3):

Insert query not matching your column use this it will work:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO crewlist(id, name,sname,linkname,description)
VALUES ('',cName,ser,link,info)";
```

this will insert cName,ser,link,info in table if you want the data use:

```
'".$cname."'
```

Comment: If you're not using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) this is not going to work reliably or safely.