# PHP rest API with call procedure

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I've often created an API like this:

```
public function getUserInfo($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE id = ? ");
    $result = array();

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $email);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $result['id'] = $id;
    $result['email'] = $email;

    return $result;
}
```

However, I need to develop the API using procedures. and My Code is not working.

```
public function getUserInfo($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("call getUser( ? )");
    $result = array();

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $email); // error here
    $stmt->fetch();

    $result['id'] = $id;
    $result['email'] = $email;

    return $result;
}
```

What I have to do for get id and email in this case?

Comment: Why are you creating stored procedures for simple `SELECT` calls? This is often very wasteful and extremely counter-productive. Just make the call. Wrap it in a function like you've done. That's the best plan.

Comment: I summarized the situation briefly. The actual procedure is more complex.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly *not working* means in your case. Is there an error message, or, maybe, WSOD at least?

Comment: This is also a problem when using simple queries such as "SELECT * FROM users". I do not know how to read parameters that are not specified in the select query..

Comment: You really should reserve stored procedures for situations where other queries are cluttered up by complicated calculations and there's no other way to simplify them, plus the logic these functions contain is unlikely to change in the future. A classic example here is GIS functions to compute distance on the 3D surface of the Earth instead of cartesian distance. You're just doing a `CALL` here so I think you're over-engineering this.

Comment: I got this error code.
 Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AppAPI/includes/DBOperation.php on line 143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `fetch()` if you want the column names as well, call [`fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php):

```
$result = $stmt->fetch_row();
```

You can delete any unnecessary columns from that structure, or add in any other fields you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your answer is very helpul to me. I tried fetch in various ways and succeeded. I finally sove it like $conn->store_result()->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Remember that some of those steps can fail, so be sure to [enable exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict) so you don't miss errors.