# Code works but takes a long time to load "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" along with the error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

It gives the output from database along with the above error: "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" on line 7.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';//content below
$sql = "select *from users";
$selected = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = "random";
while($row!=="null"){
    $row = $selected->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['username']; 
}
```

In config.php:

```
<?php
DEFINE('DB_server','localhost');
DEFINE('DB_username','root');
DEFINE('DB_password','');
DEFINE('DB_name','demo');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_server,DB_username,DB_password,DB_name);
if($mysqli===NULL){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: looks to me like you are looping forever ? what could possibly cause $row to "===" 'null' ?

Comment: `$row` will __never__ be equal to `"null"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an infinite loop. `$row` will never be equal to a string `"null"`, because `$row` is an array or a string `"random"`.

Two things. First, you should enable [error reporting for MySQLi](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting). It should always be switched on. Use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before `new mysqli`.

```
<?php
DEFINE('DB_server','localhost');
DEFINE('DB_username','root');
DEFINE('DB_password','');
DEFINE('DB_name','demo');

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_server,DB_username,DB_password,DB_name);
?>
```

Second, when you want to loop on the results of your query you can simply use foreach.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';//content below
$sql = "select *from users";
$selected = $mysqli->query($sql);
foreach($selected as $row) {
    echo $row['username']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `fetch_assoc` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php),

```
[...]

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}

[...]
```

That is how you should call it in a loop.

Comment: Please note that the PHP docs are providing very poor code examples when it comes to mysqli usage. It is much better to enable [exception mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18457822/1839439) than to display errors using `die()` and using `foreach` loop is usually simpler than `while` loop.