# How to fetch menu and sub-menu from database using nested do while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops

I kindly would like someone to help me on php code. What I want to do is to fetch Menu  and Sub-menu from database using nested do while loop from two tables so  it shows a drop-down navigation bar. Navigation table holds menu items and category table holds sub-menu. But it stops on first iteration of the loop after it fetch all menu items and the first sub-menu items for the first menu item then it shows nothing but empty result.

```
-- Table structure for table `category`
--

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nav_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_eng` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`cat_id`, `nav_id`, `cat_eng`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Technology'),
(2, 1, 'Science'),
(3, 1, 'Mathemathics'),
(4, 1, 'Computer'),
(5, 2, 'Geography'),
(6, 2, 'Environment'),
(7, 2, 'Weather'),
(8, 2, 'World'),
(9, 3, 'Sport'),
(10, 3, 'Food'),
(11, 3, 'Health'),
(12, 4, 'Mens'),
(13, 4, 'Womens');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `navigation`
--

CREATE TABLE `navigation` (
  `nav_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nav_eng` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `navigation`
--

INSERT INTO `navigation` (`nav_id`, `nav_eng`) VALUES
(1, 'Educational'),
(2, 'General-Knowlege'),
(3, 'Life-style'),
(4, 'Fashion');
```

Connection.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();

  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $dbname = 'test';

  $connection = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

  if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
 ?>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            <!-- FETCHING NAVIGATION LIST ALONG WITH DROPDOWN MENU FROM DATABASE  -->
            <?php
                //SETTING GET PAGES
                if (isset($_GET['nav'])) {
                    $pageid = $_GET['nav'];
                }else {
                    $pageid = 1;
                }

                //NAVIGATION TABLE QUERY
                 $nav_sql = "SELECT * FROM navigation";
                 $nav_query = mysqli_query($connection, $nav_sql);
                 $nav_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_query);

                 //CATEGORY TABLE QUERY
                  $cat_sql = "SELECT category.*, navigation.nav_id AS id FROM category JOIN navigation ON (category.nav_id = navigation.nav_id) WHERE category.nav_id = " .$pageid;
                  $cat_query = mysqli_query($connection, $cat_sql);
                  $cat_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query);
                do {
                  ?> 
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="?nav=<?php echo $nav_result['nav_id'] ?>"> <?php echo $nav_result['nav_eng']; ?></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <?php 
                        do { ?>
                          <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?nav=<?php echo $cat_result['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat_result['cat_eng'] ?></a>
                          </li> <?php 
                        } while ($cat_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query));
                       ?>
                    </ul>
                  </li> <?php
                } while ($nav_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_query));

             ?>
          </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: As your `$cat_query` is executed before either loop is run, the first time round the inner loop will read all of the records from the database.  The second time around there are no records left to read.  Either you need to execute this query inside the outer loop - picking the specific items, or re-position the SQL cursor at the start and re-read.

Comment: Hey Nigel! As I'm new to coding I'm stuck.  could you provide me the correct query please?!

Comment: Not sure what it should be, you have `category.nav_id = " .$pageid` at the end of the SQL, but how is `$pageid` related to each individual menu your trying to display.  If this is from the `navigation` table, then inside the first loop, fetch the particular value and execute this `category` query with the correct value for each menu.

Comment: I set ```category.nav-is = .$pageid``` is because each menu item has its nav_id in navigation table and submenu of category table also has nav_id, so when each menu is clicked I want it to dynamically fetch submenu based on nav_id passed through a ```,$_GET[]``` method. So I set this line ->``` //SETTING GET PAGES
                if (isset($_GET['nav'])) {
                    $pageid = $_GET['nav'];
                }else {
                    $pageid = 1;
                }```above

Comment: Can I clarify: Initially you wish to simply display the contents of `nav_eng` from the `navigation` table as menu items. When clicked the relevant sub-menu will be fetched and displayed under that category heading. Is that more or less correct?

Comment: RamRaider, yes! those submenu should be fetched based on navigation table of nav_id equal to category table of nav_id so the result should be dynamic. I tried it so many ways but couldn't find where where I messed it up

Comment: I believe I have a working demo of what you are trying to achieve but it is fundamentally different to the approach you took above and might be incorrect or of no interest

Comment: RamRaider: what approach you suggest and it'd be helpful for me if you let me see it

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_connect_error());` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the table definitions and data from the question I had a little play at getting a menu system working without nested queries and using `DOMDocument` to ensure that elements were written and closed correctly to avoid invalid HTML.

You could substitute your own values for the database credentials to test the following - it ought to work OK. I appreciate this is vastly different to the original and also that there are other ways to accomplish your goal - this was simply me having a playabout but it may be of use.

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush();


    /* modify as appropriate */
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';

    /* create the db connection */
    try{
        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
        $db->set_charset( 'utf8' );
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }


    /* a utility function that greatly speeds adding DOM elements with attributes and values */
    function create( $dom, $type, $attr=array(), $parent=NULL ){
        if( $dom && is_object( $dom ) && $type && !empty( $type ) && is_array( $attr ) ){
            $node = $dom->createElement( $type );
            foreach( $attr as $key => $value ){
                if( strtolower( $key )=='text' or strtolower( $key )=='nodevalue' or strtolower( $key )=='value' && $node->tagName!='input' ){
                    if( !is_object( $value ) )$node->nodeValue=$value;
                } else {
                    if( !is_null( $value ) && !is_object( $value ) ) $node->setAttribute( $key, $value );
                }
            }
            if( isset( $parent ) && is_object( $parent ) ) $parent->appendChild( $node );
            return $node;
        }
    }   

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>PHP & mySQL Database driven menu</title>
        <style>
            html *{font-family:verdana,arial;}
            a{text-decoration:none;}
            .active_cat{text-decoration:underline;font-style:italic}
            .active_subcat{color:red;font-style:italic}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
            <ul class='navbar-nav mr-auto'>
            <!-- this will be populated later -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

    /* capture & filter querystring variables */
    $nav_id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'nav', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $sub_nav_id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'subnav', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


    /* Create the basic menu of main headings based upon this simple query */
    $sql='select nav_id, nav_eng from navigation order by nav_eng asc';
    $results=$db->query( $sql );



    if( $results ){

        /* Create a new instance of DOMDocument and DOMXPath */
        libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
        $dom=new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML( ob_get_contents() );
        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
        $col=$xp->query( '//div[ @id="navbarSupportedContent" ]/ul' );

        /* We have loaded the buffer - now clear the old version */
        ob_clean();

        /* We will write new DOM elements to this fragment */
        $fragment=$dom->createDocumentFragment();

        /* Maintain an array of menu items that become parent nodes for child menus */
        $nav=array();


        while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() ){

            /* create the list elemet for this category and add the link and a child `UL` element */
            $li=create( $dom, 'li', array( 'class'=>'nav-item dropdown' ), $fragment );

            /* set the attributes for the hyperlink */
            $options=array( 'class'=>'nav-link dropdown-toggle ', 'text'=>$rs->nav_eng, 'role'=>'button', 'data-toggle'=>'dropdown', 'aria-haspopup'=>'true', 'aria-expanded'=>'false', 'href'=>sprintf( '?nav=%d', $rs->nav_id ) );
            if( $rs->nav_id==$nav_id )$options['class'] .= 'active_cat';
            /* append the hyperlink to the li element */
            $a=create( $dom, 'a', $options, $li );

            /* create the child UL element and assign a reference in the $nav array for later use */
            $ul=create( $dom, 'ul', array( 'data-category'=>$rs->nav_eng, 'data-navid'=>$rs->nav_id, 'class'=>'dropdown-menu' ), $li );

            $nav[ $rs->nav_id ]=$ul;
        }
        /* Add the fragment to the main UL*/
        $col->item(0)->appendChild( $fragment );





        /* If there is a querystring variable `nav` then we query to find child menu items */
        if( $nav_id ){

            $sql='select
                    c.cat_eng, 
                    c.cat_id,
                    c.nav_id
                from category c
                    join navigation n on c.nav_id = n.nav_id
                where c.nav_id=?
                    order by c.cat_eng';
            /* create a prepared statement and bind the nav_id value as input */
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $nav_id );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                /* The query succeeded, generate child menu items */
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $cat, $cid, $nid ); # arbitrary names to correspond to fields in recordset

                /* Find the correct parent node from the array created earlier */
                $parent=$nav[ $nav_id ];


                /* iterate through the recordset & add menu items */
                while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $options=array( 'class'=>'dropdown-item ', 'href'=>sprintf( '?nav=%d&subnav=%d', $nid, $cid ), 'text'=>$cat );
                    if( $cid==$sub_nav_id )$options['class'] .= 'active_subcat';

                    create( $dom, 'a', $options, create( $dom, 'li', array(), $parent ) );
                }

                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }

        /* render new DOM - the output buffer will now be flushed */
        exit( $dom->saveHTML() );
    }
?>
```

Comment: no problems - have you tried it? Was that the intended result?

Comment: You should still enable mysqli exception mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457821/how-to-make-mysqli-throw-exceptions-using-mysqli-report-strict and stop catching the exceptions.