# How to compare two mysql tables of the same structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with the same structure:

Table 1

```
---------------------------------------       
id    long        lat          adresse
---------------------------------------
1     8,767676    50,55599999  aaaaaa
2     3,77777777  40,55599999  xxxxxx
-
-
---------------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
---------------------------------------     
id    long        lat          adresse
---------------------------------------
1     3,77777777  40,55599999
2     
-
-
---------------------------------------
```

I want to compare `Table 1` and `Table 2` in `php/mysql` and display the `adresse` of the data row that doesn't have the same `lat` and `long` in `Table 2`.

From the example, display: `aaaaaa`.

Comment: Are you comparing them straight on `id`? or are you looking for lat, long pairs that exist in one table but not the other? I would recommend adding a few more rows and your expected results.

Comment: How large will the tables get?  There is a very quick and simple method for small tables.

Comment: exactly !! looking for lat, long pairs that exist in table1 but not in table2

Comment: my tables have over 100 rows

Comment: @crixus if that is that case, my answer should work alright. Does it give you problems?

Comment: $req= "SELECT adress
FROM table1
WHERE (lat, long) NOT IN (SELECT lat,long FROM table2)";
$res=mysql_fetch_array($req);
  while ($res!=null)
    {
        echo' adress:'.$res['adress'];
    }

Comment: what's wrong with my request ?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: thank's much for your help , i got the solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

To get the address of pairs from table one that don't exist in table two, you can use the `NOT IN` operator, like this:

```
SELECT address
FROM t1
WHERE (longitude, lat) NOT IN (SELECT longitude, lat FROM t2);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e73a/4) example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `'join'`.

```
query = "SELECT table_1.address
     FROM table_1
     JOIN table_2
     ON table_1.id = table_2.id
     WHERE table_1.lat != table_2.lat
     AND table_1.longitude != table_2.lat";

$mysqli = @new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    var_dump($result);
}

?>
```

you can also use a `sub-query` like this:

```
<?php

query = "SELECT address
         FROM table_1
         WHERE (long, lat) NOT IN (SELECT long, lat FROM table_2)";

$mysqli = @new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    var_dump($result);
}

?>
```

Comment: thank's for answer, i tried your suggestion and had this error

Comment: object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null

Comment: hey try this link for your problem, it seems like you have a problem instanciating your msqli variable
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10424510/3871208

Comment: it's ok! i know where is the problem..thank u for your help ;)

Comment: Alright, don't forget to validate the answer. I glad to help.